# How to use TwilioAuth in React Native?

Tags: react-native, twilio, twilio-api

I want to have Soft Token TOTP authentication using Twilio,
can't figure out how to use TwilioAuth in React Native.

Comment: Have any plan to use Server or Serverless technology, like firebase or AWS lamda or own server ??

Comment: no,want to use twilio chat and authy in application with no backend

Comment: You will need a server (or functions platform) for this. When you make requests to Twilio's Authy API, you should do so from a server so that you don't expose your application key. Similarly, for Twilio Programmable Chat you need to be able to generate an Access Token on the server side to give clients access to the service. What have you tried so far with this and where are you stuck?

Comment: i tried API for OTP , works fine . i will use react native twilio wrapper for chat